# Swift: extract float from byte data

Tags: swift, type-conversion, floating-point-conversion

I'm looking for a robust and elegant way to extract four big-endian bytes from an array as a Float.

I can get a UInt32 with the bits via something like this:

```
let data: [Byte] = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x86, 0x66, 0x66, 0x00]
let dataPtr = UnsafePointer<Byte>(data)
let byteOffset = 3
let bits = UnsafePointer<UInt32>(dataPtr + byteOffset)[0].bigEndian
```

But I can't figure out a good way to convert this into a Float in Swift.

For example, in Java:

```
float f = Float.intBitsToFloat(bits)
```

or in C:

```
float f = *(float *)&bits;
```

I tried casting the dataPtr to a float UnsafePointer, but then the endianness is a problem.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The floating point types have a static `_fromBitPattern` that will return a value. `<Type>._BitsType` is a type alias to the correctly sized unsigned integer:

```
let data: [Byte] = [0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x86, 0x66, 0x66, 0x00]
let dataPtr = UnsafePointer<Byte>(data)
let byteOffset = 3
let bits = UnsafePointer<Float._BitsType>(dataPtr + byteOffset)[0].bigEndian
let f = Float._fromBitPattern(bits)
```

You don't see that method in auto-completion, but it's a [part of the `FloatingPointType` protocol](http://swifter.natecook.com/protocol/FloatingPointType/). There's an instance method that will give you back the bits, called `._toBitPattern()`.

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent Swift code is

```
let flt = unsafeBitCast(bits, Float.self)
```

which gives `4.2` with your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution for Swift 3:

```
Float(bitPattern: bits)
```