# Extract float from byte data

Tags: swift, swift3, type-conversion, endianness

I need to extract some listmode bigEndian Float data from a binary file format. I was originally using the following method and it worked perfectly, but I am having trouble converting this over to Swift 3...

Original: (example of 20 rows with 15 columns of data that start after 300 bytes of header)

```
let fileData: NSData = NSData(contentsOfFile: fileInfo.path)!
let ptr = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(fileData.bytes)
let byteOffset = 300
for i in 0..<20 {

    let byteOffset2 = byteOffset + (i * 15 * 4)

    for p in 0..<15 {
        let bits = UnsafePointer<Float._BitsType>(ptr + byteOffset2)[p].bigEndian
        let f = Float._fromBitPattern(bits)
        eventData[p] = f
    }
}
```

New: (after the automated Xcode conversion and some attempted tweaking to remove errors in Xcode)

```
let fileData: Data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileInfo.path))
let ptr = (fileData as NSData).bytes.bindMemory(to: UInt32.self, capacity: fileData.count)
let byteOffset = 300

for i in 0..<20 {

    let byteOffset2 = byteOffset + (i * 15 * 4)

    for p in 0..<15 {
        let bits = UnsafePointer<UInt32>(ptr + byteOffset2)[p].bigEndian 
        let f = Float(bitPattern: bits)
        eventData[p] = f
    }
}
```

The values generated from the new method are now incorrect... I have been fiddling for quite a while now and I am stumped - any advice would be much appreciated. I found my original method in this question/answer: [Swift: extract float from byte data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976579/swift-extract-float-from-byte-data) but it seems that Float._BitsType doesn't work in Swift 3. Any advice will be much appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

The problem (if I guess correctly) is that `ptr` in your attempted
Swift 3 code is a pointer to `UInt32` and not to `UInt8` as in the 
Swift 2 version. Therefore `ptr + byteOffset2` advances the pointer
by `4 * byteOffset2` bytes, and that must be considered when computing
the offsets.

Generally you can simplify the access to `Data` like this:

```
data.withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt32>) in

    let uint32Offset = 300/MemoryLayout<UInt32>.stride // 300/4 = 75

    for i in 0 ..< 20 {
        for p in 0 ..< 15 {

            let offset = uint32Offset + i * 15 + p
            let u32Value = UInt32(bigEndian: ptr[offset])
            let floatValue = Float(bitPattern: u32Value)
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, unfortunately this still didn't work for me - you are right that it is the change to the UInt32 that seems to be the problem... In the end I have it working by using an UInt8 pointer and then converting to UInt32 before taking into account the endianness... I feel like it is the long way around and can see it looks ugly, but it is the first time I have it working at all. Is there a more direct way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any more suggestions, this is what worked for me. I can see it is pretty ugly and could do with some clean up. I couldn't seem to get the data any other way than using a UInt8 pointer (no matter how I adjusted the offset). Because of the endian problem, I tried to make a [UInt8] array and then convert that to UInt32. It is working, but any improvements would be very welcome...

```
fileData.withUnsafeBytes { (ptr: UnsafePointer<UInt8>) in
let byteOffset = 300
for i in 0..<20 {
    let byteOffset2 = byteOffset + (i * 15 * 4)
    for p in 0..<15 {
            var bitsArray = [UInt8]()
            for b in 0..<4 {
                let bits4 = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(ptr + byteOffset2 + b)[p * 4]
                bitsArray.append(bits4)
            }
            let bigEndianValue = bitsArray.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
                            ($0.baseAddress!.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt32.self, capacity: 1) { $0 })
                            }.pointee
            let u32Value = UInt32(bigEndian: bigEndianValue)
            let f = Float(bitPattern: u32Value)
            eventData[p] = f
        }
    }
}
```